# named (bind DNS) not quitting

Tags: dns, macos

I am trying to quit named, but it keeps popping up. I tried removing the configuration an key files, unloading it from launchd, you name it. Yet it keeps starting. How do I kill it permanently?

Comment: You need to figure out what keeps restarting it. Are you sure you unloaded it successfully from launchd?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. But I have just figured out what it was. The Internet Sharing option in System Preferences also launches an instance of named. Quit it, and named stopped popping up.