# How to run 'named' (bind) on Sierra?

Tags: macos, launchd, dns

Many OS versions ago, I ran a local copy of 'bind' for my in-home LAN.  I noticed that it made a huge difference in the speed of name resolution.  Performance of my local internet connections is **terrible**, so I want this to happen again.¹

My copy of Server.app has disappeared and this library has blocked connections to the app store.  And my caching DNS server is not running.  I still have all the configuration files, but I don't recall how to get it to run at boot.

When I originally set it up, launchd didn't exist and I didn't have Server.

I see that [Internet Sharing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83447/named-bind-dns-not-quitting) will start it, but I usually want that left OFF.

I've hunted through the LaunchAgents and Launchd but the only bind, dns, or named in file name or contents are related to crypto, mDNS, and extensions for DDNS.

Also strike out with dns, named, or bind in man and apropos.

I just saw an item in "Similar Questions" that sounded promising, but it vanished on a refresh just as I was getting ready to click on it!

¹It's so (not) convenient to try to search for 'bind' or 'named' on the web!  “Why is the new OS **named** Sierra?”

With Homebrew, I got bind-9.11.0-P3 installed and running, but after two successful test lookups, the third and subsequent said

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
```

which in the named.log shows that it failed to access the root nameservers (how the first two lookups succeeded baffles me).

Comment: After I resolved errors in (or created by) "homebrew", it is returning addresses, but logging zillions of errors each lookup.  To go any further is more on-topic for SuperUser SE.

Comment: It's now running, but I hate to put "brew install bind" as an answer because (1) brew had several errors which I had to manually correct; and (2) it's running, but it's not caching, and it's logging lots of errors.  http://superuser.com/questions/1182664/why-do-dig-nslookup-and-host-cause-named-to-have-errors